# cudaStreamSynchronize(nullptr) == cudaDeviceSynchronize()?

Tags: cuda

Assuming:

1. [legacy default stream](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/stream-sync-behavior.html#stream-sync-behavior__default-stream)
2. single-threaded program
3. only using runtime API (i.e. single implicit `CUcontext`)

what is the difference between

```cpp
cudaStreamSynchronize(nullptr);
// and
cudaDeviceSynchronize();
```

if any

Answer (score 3):

Let recall the behavior of each component:

1 - [cudaStreamSynchronize](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__STREAM.html#group__CUDART__STREAM_1g82b5784f674c17c6df64affe618bf45e) : Blocks until stream has completed all operations.

2 - [cudaDeviceSynchronize](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__DEVICE.html#group__CUDART__DEVICE_1g10e20b05a95f638a4071a655503df25d) : Blocks until device (or `CUcontext` in your case) has completed all operations.

3 - [legacy default stream](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/stream-sync-behavior.html#stream-sync-behavior__default-stream) : When an action is taken, the legacy stream first **waits on all blocking streams**.

The difference apear if you use **non-blocking streams** created with [cudaStreamCreateWithFlags](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__STREAM.html#group__CUDART__STREAM_1gb1e32aff9f59119e4d0a9858991c4ad3)  and the flag `cudaStreamNonBlocking`.

So if you have the following code:

```
cudaStreamCreateWithFlags( stream_0, cudaStreamNonBlocking );
cudaStreamCreate( stream_1 );

...

cudaStreamSynchronize( nullptr ); // sync with stream_1 and legacy stream
cudaDeviceSynchronize(); // sync with stream_0, stream_1 and legacy
```

--------- edit

As some users can't reproduce this behavior, I provide a minimal example:

```
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

void CUDART_CB callback(cudaStream_t stream, cudaError_t status, void * user_data)
{
    sleep( *((int*) user_data) );
}

int main()
{
    std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point begin, end;
    cudaStream_t stream_0, stream_1;
    
    cudaStreamCreateWithFlags( &stream_0, cudaStreamNonBlocking );
    cudaStreamCreate( &stream_1 );

    int a = 1;
    int b = 10;

    cudaStreamAddCallback( stream_1, callback, &a, 0 );
    cudaStreamAddCallback( stream_0, callback, &b, 0 );
    
    begin = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    cudaStreamSynchronize( nullptr );
    end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    std::cout << "Time difference = " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - begin).count() << "[ms]" << std::endl;

    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    return 0;
}
```

Tested on CUDA 10.2 (Hardware: Jetson Nano) and CUDA 11.2 (Hardware A100).

Output:

```
Time difference = 1001[ms]
```

The call to `cudaStreamSynchronize( nullptr )` does not synchronize with `stream_0` as this stream sleep for 10 secondes.

Comment: I manage to get the expected behavior with cuda 10.2 on Jetson Nano, I edit the answer to provide the full code.